# dynamically insert javascript into <head> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, cewp

I am using CEWP (webpart) and putting this code in there. But this code is not going inside `<head>` tag. I need to insert this code in `<head>` tag,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("*").each(function () { if ($(this).children().length == 0) { $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Respuesta','Responder')); } });
</script>
```

How can I do this? How this code will work in CEWP webpart?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can put the code in the `<head>` if you set it to run at document ready time.

However, it's still not going to work. You're iterating over *all* tags. Including `<html>`, which will be the first one selected by `$('*')`.

So you read all the text inside the `<html>` element (ie. the entire document text), do a string replace on it, then write it back to the html `text()`. Replacing all the previous text and element content of the `<html>` element with a single simple text string. And thereby destroying every other element on the page. Oops.

What you want to do is find every text node and do a separate string replace on it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').each(function() {
        for (var i= this.childNodes.length; i-->0;) {
            var child= this.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType===3) // TEXT_NODE
                child.data= child.data.replace(/Respuesta/g, 'Responder');
        }
    });
});
```

(Note there are still a bunch of possible edge cases here with form fields and other elements where changing the text inside them might not do what you expect.)

Comment: You can put that javascript wherever you want, but don't forget to _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myFunction")